# Limit user actions in a 24 hour period and reset counter after time elapses

Tags: python

I would like to create a function that starts off by checking the time in a given timezone and limits the number of actions a person can carry within  a 24 hour period. Note this function will have to constantly check the time- every single time a person interacts with it and it should reset the counter to 0 after a 24 hour period

I have create a 'hacky' solution that checks whether the time is between 1am and 2300hrs and then adds adds 1 to a counter each time a person carries out an action. I then added an if statement to check if the counter exceeds 5 and then print out a message if that happens.

However, I fear that this is the most efficient way to do this.

Here is my code

```
current_day = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Africa/Harare'))if (0 <= time.hour) and (1 <= time.minute)
counter = 0 
while (1 <= current_day.hour <= 23):
    action
    counter +=1
    if counter > 5:
        print('You have to wait until 1 in the morning tomorrow to get another 5 tries')
        break
```

Comment: Not only is this not efficient, I don't see how it solves the problem.  If the limit is 20 and your user attempts one per hour, she should get denied for 4 hours and then allowed access again.  Please show the current output from one or two sample runs, so we get a solid grasp of your desired solution.

Comment: @Prune I understand that hence the question. The idea is to cap requests in a 24 hour period to 5. So a user can only make 5 requests in a given day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method below will be more elegant because it will count time from first action, not start of day.

```
sessionStorage = {} # stores information about user session (time of first action and action counter)

# adds user to session storage with current time and set action counter to 0 
def add_user(user):
    sessionStorage[user] = {}
    sessionStorage[user][time] = datetime.datetime.now()
    sessionStorage[user][counter] = 0

# checks if user can perform action and update action time if needed
def can_perform_action(user)
    difference = sessionStorage[user][time] - datetime.datetime.now()
    if difference.hours > 24: # check if there lasts 24 hours after first action
        # if so, reset action counter and set last action time to current ime
        sessionStorage[user][counter] = 0
        sessionStorage[user][time] = datetime.datetime.now()
    # if action counter is more than 5, then do not allow action
    if sessionStorage[user][counter] > 5:
        return False
    # in all other cases allow action
    return True

# increment action counter for current user
def increment_action_counter(user):
    sessionStorage[user][counter] += 1


def main():
    add_user(user) # create new user

    if can_perform_action(user): # check if this user can perform action
        # perform action and ...
        increment_action_counter(user) # increment action counter
```

Comment: Updated post with comments

Comment: posted another question with the full code I am using, maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822008/getting-a-view-does-not-return-a-valid-response-error-message-on-my-flask-chatbo